# STS Database Connection Ping Failed

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database so I will reverse engineer the tables into classes on a Spring Boot Project. When I enter the properties and , after adding the jar file, and trying to test the connection it says `Ping failed!`

Selecting Database perspective through STS

[image]

Trying to create you database connection

[image]

Connection profile with properties

[image]

The jar

[image]

Testing the connection

[image]

The exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Generic JDBC
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:814)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCConnectionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0):

Driver name should be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`